# Proving the equation $k = {1 \over 2} + \sqrt{(k-1) * k + {1 \over 4}}$

Tags: analysis, functions, discrete-mathematics, coloring

So I've done some calculations and it seems that formula is true for any $k >= 1$ and $ k \in {\mathbb N }$. Does anyone has a hint which definition or way of rewriting could help me to prove it?
$$k = {1 \over 2} + \sqrt{(k-1) * k + {1 \over 4}}$$
Thank you,
Simonmicro

EDIT: Btw thats the origin: $ \chi(G) <= {1 \over 2} + \sqrt{ 2 * |E| + {1 \over 4}} $ with |E| = $\binom {\chi(G)} 2$

Comment: $(a-b)^2=a^2+b^2-2ab$.

Comment: In fact $k\ge\frac12$ can be arbitrary real number .

Comment: Yeah, that's right - but at my problem the limit for the k was higher and made more sense (discrete mathematics: k was the number of edges in a graph).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Use that $$(k-1)k+\frac{1}{4}=k^2-k+\frac{1}{4}=\left(k-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$$

Comment: Bloody hell! How could I not see that?! Thank you, you saved my day!

Comment: I hope it will be a nice day!

Comment: Good and clear.

Answer (score 1):

It's
$$k-\frac{1}{2}=\left|k-\frac{1}{2}\right|,$$ which is $$k\geq\frac{1}{2}.$$